# How to get updated access token for google api using refresh token (php)?

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-authentication

For the code to work, the official library from Google is used to work with the API through PHP.

```
// connect the library to work with the Google API
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
echo '<pre>';
```

In this example, all keys are set manually.

```
$array = '{"access_token":"***","expires_in":3599,"scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/calendar https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/userinfo.profile openid https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/userinfo.email","token_type":"Bearer","id_token":"****","created":1644878660,"refresh_token":"**************"}';
print_r($array);

// Application Options
// Application ID
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', '************');
// Secret Apps
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', '*********************');
// The address to which the user will be redirected after authorization
define('GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', 'https://*************/api/google-login.php');
```

Areas to which access will be requested.

```
// Areas to which access will be requested
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', [
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
]));

// Initializing the Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

// Retrieving a token from an array
$accessToken = json_decode($array, true);
print_r($accessToken);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Actually the area that raises the most questions.

```
// If the token has expired, update it
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
 
    // When refreshing a refresh token, the token is missing
    // Therefore, we save the refresh token in a separate variable
    $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();
 
    // Refreshing the token
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);
 
    // We create a new variable in which we place the new updated token
    $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();
 
    // Add the old refresh token to this variable
    $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;
 
    // Installing a new token
    $client->setAccessToken($accessTokenUpdated);
    
    
    echo $refreshTokenSaved.'<br>';
    print_r($accessTokenUpdated);
    echo '<br>';
    
}
```

We display the result of the request for user data to check the validity of the access token.

```
if (!$client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    $userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
    
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'Email: ';
    echo $userInfo->email;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'sex: ';
    echo $userInfo->gender;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'name: ';
    echo $userInfo->givenName;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'Surname: ';
    echo $userInfo->familyName;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'Full name: ';
    echo $userInfo->name;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'ID: ';
    echo $userInfo->id;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo 'Photo link: ';
    echo $userInfo->picture;
    echo '<br><br>';
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}

echo '</pre>';
```

Please check my code. Right now it's returning the old (invalid) access token. Thanks!

Comment: _"We display the result of the request for user data to check the validity of the access token."_ - and you got a result, so you must be using a valid token. You say it was the old one, so if that is really the case and it is still valid - then why should the code block wrapped in `if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())` even execute ...?